# How to update the Z value using an UpdateCursor?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, elevation, cursor

I have created the following script to mimic the ArcGIS 3D Analyst tool, FeatureTo3DByAttribute, which creates a 3D copy of a 2D feature class and sets the Z to a specified attribute.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

# Parameters
in_features = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)   #Feature Layer
out_features = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  #Feature Class
height_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)  #Field

# disable overwrite protection
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# enable environment outputZFlag
arcpy.env.outputZFlag = "Enabled"

# copy input to output
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features, out_features)

# Use cursor to update geometry with z value based on height_field
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(out_features, ("SHAPE@Z", height_field)) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = row[1]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Unfortunately, the z value is 0 for all of the output features.  I can't find any documentation as to why this is.  An alternative would be read every point and change the z value.  Does anyone know why it is failing to update the z?

EDIT:
Additional discussion

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/93322

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/82123

Comment: Are the geometries Z aware? In the Catalog property view the Has Z values is ticked isn't it? That code looks sound so the problem may be elsewhere. Isn't it arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(out_features, ["SHAPE@Z", height_field]) for the cursor? Would square brackets here make much of a difference - tupple vs list?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Thanks for the comment.  The geometries are Z aware.  I have tried brackets and parentheses with the same result.  I ran the code in a shell and I can read and write the z values using the cursor.  I delete the cursor and create it again, and the z values are back to 0.  Is it read only with a cursor?

Comment: It shouldn't be read-only. You could try a non-da cursor, read the shape, modify the Z on the shape and set the shape back - use getValue(height_field) to obtain the Z. All my Zaware (python) code is v10 which is before the arcpy.da cursors and works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and I solved it by simply setting the "has_z" property to TRUE while creating the polygon geometry: arcpy.Polygon(my_array, my_spat_ref, TRUE). In the code below I update the z value of the vertices of my polygon fc taking the z values of a point fc.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "my_path"
point_fc="my_points_fc.shp"
polygon_fc = "my_pol_fc.shp"
my_field = "SHAPE@"
my_field_pnt = "SHAPE@XYZ"


with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(polygon_fc, my_field) as myUpdtCur:
    for row in myUpdtCur:
        geom = row[0]
        arr_pol = arcpy.Array()
        for part in geom:            
            arr_part = arcpy.Array()
            pnt_count = 0
            for pnt in part:
                with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(point_fc, my_field_pnt) as mySrcCur:
                    for srcPnt in mySrcCur:
                        if int(pnt.X) == int(srcPnt[0][0]) and int(pnt.Y) == int(srcPnt[0][1]):

                            updZpnt=srcPnt[0][2]                         
                del mySrcCur
                pnt_count += 1                
                print pnt_count
                myXYZPoint = arcpy.Point(pnt.X, pnt.Y, updZpnt)
                arr_part.add(myXYZPoint)
            arr_pol.add(arr_part)
        ## here is where I create my polygon and set the "has_z" property to true, otherwise it dosn't write the z value
        polygon = arcpy.Polygon(arr_pol,None, True) 
        row[0] = polygon
        myUpdtCur.updateRow(row)
del myUpdtCur
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the da.Updatecursor, I tried modifying the z values of individual vertices, creating a new geometry object, and replacing the existing geometry with the z-modified geometry.

```
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(out_features, ["SHAPE@", height_field])
for row in cursor:
    newGeom = arcpy.Array()
    for part in row[0].getPart():
        newPart = arcpy.Array()
        for pnt in part:
            if pnt != None:
                newPnt = arcpy.Point(pnt.X, pnt.Y, row[1])
                newPart.add(newPnt)
        newGeom.add(newPart)
    newShape = arcpy.Polyline(newGeom)
    row[0] = newShape
    cursor.updateRow(row)
del row, cursor
```

This does not work.  Unfortunately, there seems to be something in the da cursor that does not like applying the new geometry.  As per the suggestion of @MichaelMiles-Stimson, I replaced the da.UpdateCursor (above) with an older UpdateCursor (below), and it works perfectly.  A little slow for my liking, but it works.

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(out_features)
for row in cursor:
    geom = row.getValue(shapefield)
    elev = row.getValue(height_field)
    newGeom = arcpy.Array()
    for part in geom:
        newPart = arcpy.Array()
        for pnt in part:
            if pnt != None:
                newPnt = arcpy.Point(pnt.X, pnt.Y, elev)
                newPart.add(newPnt)
        newGeom.add(newPart)
    newShape = arcpy.Polyline(newGeom)
    row.setValue(shapefield, newShape)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
del row, cursor
```

I am posting this answer because it works, but I'd still like to know why the da.UpdateCursor methods do not work.  In theory they should, but the documentation of their usage in this area is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the 'Feature To 3D By Attribute (3D Analyst)' tool.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q90000002z000000

Comment: If you read the question, it states that I am trying to get around using that tool which requires a license.

Comment: Oops. I scanned over that.