# Update Z values on a line

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, geometry, z-value

I'm using ArcMap 10.1. I want to select all vertices that contain z values and decrease their value with -0,155 meter but I dont want to change vertices that have the value=0.
With this script I managed to change all vertices but how can I change it to only update those with a value?

```
fc = r'C:\Users\tomlin01\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\Export_Output_8'    #layer to update
z_increase = -0,155         #change in meters
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, 'SHAPE@Z', explode_to_points=True) as cursor:    
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.updateRow([row[0] + z_increase])
```

Comment: i think first you need to select them and run your script only on selected vertices. Check this topic: [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135916/how-to-update-the-z-value-using-an-updatecursor)[link]

Answer (score 1):

Add an if statement:

```
fc = r'C:\Users\tomlin01\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\Export_Output_8'    #layer to update
z_increase = -0,155         #change in meters
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, 'SHAPE@Z', explode_to_points=True) as cursor:    
    for row in cursor:
        if (row[0]<>0 and row[0] is not None):
            cursor.updateRow([row[0] + z_increase])
```

Comment: Please accept my answer with the checkmark symbol