# Shapefile not Z-enabled although the environment is Z-enabled in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, point, cursor, feature-class

My attempt is to view raster values in the command window. The follwing code is thought to do this by converting the raster to a point feature file and by successively scanning the values at the points:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join('H:\\','myexample')
arcpy.env.outputZFlag = 'Enabled'
arcpy.conversion.RasterToPoint('myraster','mypointfeaturefile.shp')
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('mypointfeaturefile.shp', 'SHAPE@XYZ') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print(u'{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
```

The `arcpy.conversion.RasterToPoint` process works fine: a raster value can be retrieved from `mypointfeaturefile.shp` in ArcGIS Pro by activating `Explore` and clicking onto a point of `mypointfeaturefile.shp`. Therefore, the points in `mypointfeaturefile.shp` seem to hold raster values as Z-values. However, the 6th line `for row in cursor` returns the error message:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot find field 'SHAPE@XYZ'. Input feature class is not M- or Z-enabled.
```

I was following the [SearchCursor documentation together](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) with [Barbarossa's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135916/how-to-update-the-z-value-using-an-updatecursor) case and assumed that the point feature file would be Z-enabled by the 3rd line

```
arcpy.env.outputZFlag = 'Enabled'
```

However, this does not seem to be the case. What am I missing in this process to make `mypointfeaturefile.shp` Z-enabled?

System:

- OS: Windows 11 Pro, 21H2
- arcpy: version 3.11.1

Comment: You do not say which software you are using and it's version.

Comment: The resulting shapefile is probably 2D. You'd need to pass it through a surface to pick up a Z value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raster to Point doesn't add Z information, it just creates an attribute in the output 2D feature class's attribute table.  From the [Raster To Point](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-point.htm) documentation:

> Converts a raster dataset to point features.
>
> Usage
>
> ...
>
> The Field parameter allows you to choose which attribute field of
> the input raster dataset will become **an attribute in the output
> feature class**. If a field is not specified, the cell values of the
> input raster (the VALUE field) will become a column with the heading
> GRID_CODE in the attribute table of the output feature class.

You need a 3D Analyst license and to run the [Feature To 3D By Attribute](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/feature-to-3d-by-attribute.htm) tool on the output of Raster to Point to create a 3D feature class

```
import arcpy, os

# if running outside of ArcGIS or inside ArcGIS without 3D already checked out
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")

arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join('H:\\','myexample')
arcpy.env.outputZFlag = 'Enabled'
arcpy.conversion.RasterToPoint('myraster','point2D.shp')
arcpy.ddd.FeatureTo3DByAttribute('point2D.shp', 'point3D.shp', 'GRID_CODE')

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('point3D.shp', 'SHAPE@XYZ') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # note row is a tuple of requested fields, and you only asked for one field 
        # so row[0] == SHAPE@XYZ
        # however SHAPE@XYZ also returns a tuple 
        # so you need row[0][x],row[0][y],row[0][z]
        print(u'{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(row[0][0], row[0][1], row[0][2]))
```